# Retrieve Specific image from SD Card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I don’t want to open any gallery view. I know the name of an image e.g.: blabla.jpg, which is stored in memory card. I want to retrieve that specie image hardcoded and shown in an image view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to load image from SD card that you can try below code.

```
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/blabla.jpg", options);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: omg ,, thanx herry , its working dude,,, i was so much messed that i lost hopes even,,

Comment: Actually the image i am retriving is not coming full, only a part of the image is coming in the Bitmap. i have changed the inSampleSize = 1 , then it gave force close,,,,,,,, plz help, i want the full image to be visible in the imageview

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ImageView.setImageUri(Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/blabla.jpg").toString()));
```

Comment: May be if image is to much big it will run out of memory.